# Duplicate entries of installed applications after for loop

Tags: android, loops, android-permissions

I am trying to get a list of applications that uses my location permission in my applications and I'm trying to get the applications that uses the location permission:

```
    public void getPermissions(Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final List<PackageInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        for (PackageInfo pi : apps) {
            String[] permissions = pi.requestedPermissions;
            if (permissions != null) {
                for (String permission : permissions) {
                    Log.d("TAG", permission);
                                if (permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER")) {

                                    String appname=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                                    //ImageView appicon;

                                    //appicon = pi.applicationInfo.setImageDrawable(packageManager);
                                    // Log.e("TAG", "Permission found for "+ appname);

                                    locationArray.add(appname);
                                }
                }
            }
        }
   } //end of getPermissions method
```

But with this i will get multiple entries like

```
Angry Birds
Angry Birds
CWM
CWM
CWM
Facebook
```

Is there any workaround to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal to get duplicate entries because you step over **all** the permissions of a `PackageInfo` and test each one to see if it is one of the location related permission. For example, as you iterate the permission of the Angry Birds game you'll come across two permission(if I'm not mistaken ACCESS_FINE and ACCESS_COARSE) and because those permissions both fulfill the if condition you'll end up adding the Angry Birds two times.

The trick is to break out of the `for (String permission : permissions)` when you find the first permission:

```
for (String permission : permissions) {
                    Log.d("TAG", permission);
                                if (permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS") || permission.equals("android.permission.ACCESS_INSTALL_LOCATION_PROVIDER")) {

                                    String appname=pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
                                    //ImageView appicon;

                                    //appicon = pi.applicationInfo.setImageDrawable(packageManager);
                                    // Log.e("TAG", "Permission found for "+ appname);

                                    locationArray.add(appname);
                                    break;   
                                }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

If You do not want duplicates You can add all contents of locationArray to HashSet(which will not allow duplicates) and add HashSet back to locationArray.

```
// add elements to hs, including duplicates
HashSet hs = new HashSet();
hs.addAll(localArray);
localArray.clear();
localArray.addAll(hs);
```

Now localArray will not have any duplicates.